# Group date rows to defined sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Date    Member  Episode
1/1/2023    A   1
1/5/2023    A   1
5/1/2023    A   2
5/5/2023    A   2
10/1/2023   A   3
1/15/2023   B   1
1/20/2023   B   1
7/1/2023    B   2
7/15/2023   B   2
7/28/2023   B   2
```

I'd like to group member+date to episodes. 30 (or any number) since the minimum date is the breaker for a new episode. I tried something that could easily handle two episodes, but not for three or more episodes.

```
UPDATE
SET IsEpisod = 1
WHERE (DaysSinMin = 0 OR DaysSinMin > 30)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Comment: So the minimum number of days is from the first row in an episode, not from the previous row?

Answer (score 0):

Because the group assignment determination for each row potentially depends on the result for every preceding row, this cannot be done using without using iterative or recursive logic. Luckily, SQL `Common Table Expressions` (CTEs) support recursion and can be used to progressively test and assign the grouping dates and episode numbers.

Something like:

```
;WITH CTE_Numbered AS (
    SELECT
        D.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Member ORDER BY Date) AS RowNum
    FROM Data D
),
CTE_Grouped AS (
    SELECT
        N.*,
        1 AS Episode,
        N.Date AS BaseDate
    FROM CTE_Numbered N
    WHERE N.RowNum = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        N.*,
        G.Episode + A.NewEpisode AS Episide,
        CASE WHEN A.NewEpisode = 0 THEN G.BaseDate ELSE N.Date END AS BaseDate
    FROM CTE_Grouped G
    JOIN CTE_Numbered N
        ON N.Member = G.Member
        AND N.RowNum = G.RowNum + 1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, G.BaseDate, N.Date) > 30
               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NewEpisode
    ) A
)
SELECT G.Date, G.Member, G.Episode, G.Expected
FROM CTE_Grouped G
ORDER BY G.Member, G.RowNum
```

The above code first uses a CTE to assign sequential numbers to each row (per member) so that it will be easier to select the next row later.

Next, a recursive CTE is used to compare dates and assign a new base date and episode number whenever the 30 day window is exceeded. The CTE works in two parts. (1) The initial row (`RowNum = 1`) is retrieved and set as the start of episode 1. (2) After that, the recursive part of the CTE retrieves the next row and compares dates to determine whether or not a new episode needs to be assigned. It will select either the existing or new base date and episode number as needed.

Results (with additional test data):

| Date | Member | Episode | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | A | 1 | Initial episode for A |
| 2023-01-05 | A | 1 |  |
| 2023-05-01 | A | 2 | New episode |
| 2023-05-05 | A | 2 |  |
| 2023-10-01 | A | 3 | New episode |
| 2023-01-15 | B | 1 | Initial episode for B |
| 2023-01-20 | B | 1 |  |
| 2023-07-01 | B | 2 | New episode |
| 2023-07-15 | B | 2 |  |
| 2023-07-28 | B | 2 |  |
| 2023-05-01 | C | 1 | Additional data to show episode breaks > 30 days |
| 2023-05-15 | C | 1 |  |
| 2023-05-30 | C | 1 | 29 days from prior start |
| 2023-05-31 | C | 1 | 30 days from prior start |
| 2023-06-01 | C | 2 | 31 days from prior start - new episode |
| 2023-06-15 | C | 2 |  |
| 2023-06-30 | C | 2 | 29 days from prior start |
| 2023-07-01 | C | 2 | 30 days from prior start |
| 2023-07-02 | C | 3 | 31 days from prior start - new episode |
| 2023-07-03 | C | 3 |  |

Note the breaks for member C at 2023-06-01 and 2023-07-02 showing breaks within closely spaced dates when the difference from episode start exceeds 30 days.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2uCmRhqT) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option without the recursion.

```
    declare @tt table ([Date] date, Member char(1), Episode int);

insert into @tt([date], member) values
('1/1/2023','A')
,('1/5/2023'    ,'A')
,('5/1/2023'    ,'A')
,('5/5/2023'    ,'A')
,('10/1/2023'   ,'A')
,('1/15/2023'   ,'B')
,('1/20/2023'   ,'B')
,('7/1/2023'    ,'B')
,('7/15/2023'   ,'B')
,('7/28/2023'   ,'B')
;
with cte as(
    select *
    , LAG([date]) over (partition by member order by [date]) as PrevDate
    from @tt
)select [Date], Member  
, 1+sum(case when DATEDIFF(day, prevDate, [date])>30 then 1 else 0 end ) over(partition by member order by [date]) as Episode
from cte
```

Comment: I don't think the above will satisfy the "30 days since minimum date" rule. If I add `,('8/1/2023', 'B'),('8/15/2023', 'B')` to the test data, they remain part of episode 2 even though 31 and 45 days have elapsed from the episode start - `7/1/2023`.